# Mailx is is not working

Tags: linux, email, postfix, mailx

I have been trying to send emails throw Linux using

> echo "hi abhijeet2" | mailx -v Admin abhijeet123@gmail.com

Whic works fine on other linux system ,but not working my system. I have tried to troubleshoot  it.When i do

> service postfix status

It shows : master dead but pid file exists

I have tried many post suggested.But could't reslove this issue.

My mail log looks like :

> Jul 14 09:38:02 postfix/postqueue[12757]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
>    fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
>   Jul 14 10:03:33  postfix/postfix-script[13969]: warning: not owned by postfix: /var/lib/postfix/./master.lock
>   Jul 14 10:03:33  postfix/postfix-script[13982]: starting the Postfix mail system
>   Jul 14 10:03:33  postfix/master[13983]: fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: cannot open file: Permission denied
>   Jul 14 10:04:10  postfix/postqueue[14015]: fatal: Cannot flush mail queue - mail system is down
>   Jul 14 10:20:48  postfix/postqueue[14549]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by using :

chown postfix.postfix -R /var/lib/postfix

Comment: @DanielYCLin : I have accepted :)

Comment: To let it clear, maybe it is better to describe your OS. Check `cat /etc/*release`